# Групповые делегаты

Tags: c#, делегаты

```
Action a1 = () => Console.Write(1); 
Action a2 = () => Console.Write(2); 
Action a3 = () => Console.Write(3); 
((a1 + a2 + a3) - (a1 + a2))(); 
((a1 + a2 + a3) - (a1 + a3))();
```

Увидел данный пример и стало интересно. Как в данном случае отрабатывает удаление делегата. Что происходит при (a1 + a2) и (a1 + a3), и почему первый вариант удаляет как надо а второй не срабатывает вовсе?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пускай `a1 + a2 + a3` превращается в делегат, который условно обозначим `[a1, a2, a3]`, `a1 + a2` -- `[a1, a2]`, `a1 + a3` -- `[a1, a3]`.

При вычитании в `[a1, a2, a3]` ищется кусок *подряд*, который равен вычитаемому. Для `[a1, a2]` такой кусок найдётся, начиная с индекса 0, а для `[a1, a3]` -- нет. Поэтому при вычитании `[a1, a2, a3] - [a1, a2]` получается `[a3]`, а при вычитании `[a1, a2, a3] - [a1, a3]` подходящий кусок не находится, и вычитание не происходит.

---

Смысл такого правила в том, что если уж делегат получен сложением одного списка с другими, то это первый список будет найден в суммарном делегате как подсписок. Поэтому вычитание в этом случае имеет смысл.

---

Цитата из стандарта, параграф 7.8.5:

> ... Результатом является новый список вызова, состоящий из списка первого операнда с удалёнными элементами списка второго операнда, при условии, что второй список является непрерывным (нетривиальным) подсписком первого [...] В противном случае, результатом является вычитаемое.

Comment: А где можно исходники найти? а то я что-то на вот этом остановился: [RemoveImpl](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/delegate.cs,77ac7b1a61c38406) и [CombineImpl](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/delegate.cs,8f8f0b7b388c5f1b,references)

Comment: @Grundy: По идее, нужно смотреть в `MulticastDelegate`.

Comment: @Grundy: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/multicastdelegate.cs,428 ?

Comment: точно! [CombineImpl](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/multicastdelegate.cs,fcbf8bdc05d28aeb,references) и  [RemoveImpl](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/multicastdelegate.cs,89414467eca8bd75,references)

Comment: Заходи в чат по .NET :) там может будет интересно :)

Comment: @Grundy: Ага :)

Comment: @VladD а стандарт этот это msdn?

Comment: @MikhailZnak: Это официальная спецификация языка. Она есть и на MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx